# Visited tags' colors should not become blue on meta.

Tags: bug, status-completed, design, css

Non-moderator tags of meta become blue when visited. In particular, this makes required tags and normal tags almost indistinguishable. It is reproducible on IE 8 and Firefox 4.

[image]

The tags' colors should not change even if they are visited. This problem only appears on meta.math.SE, but not on the parent site (math.SE).